# Balls gradually coming down in sdl

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I wrote the program below in cpp, I want the balls that I have drawn above the screen to comedown gradually so the user can be able to see it, but I can't figure out what to do

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL2_gfx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

int chance = 30;
const int radius = 25;
const int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 800;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer *rend = nullptr;

    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN, &win, &rend);
    if(!win || !rend)
    {
        cout<<"[-] ERROR: "<<SDL_GetError()<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int RColor[5] = {248, 148, 199, 0, 101};
    int GColor[5] = {222, 0, 0, 121, 183};
    int BColor[5] = {34, 255, 57, 255, 65};
    int colornumber[5] = {0};

    //rgb(248, 222, 34) yellow
    //rgb(148, 0, 255) purple
    //rgb(199, 0, 57) red
    //rgb(0, 121, 255)
    //filling the page with balls

   int y = radius;

    for(int i=1; i<=8; i++){

        int random = 0;
        if(i%2==1){
            int x1 = radius;
            for(int j=1; j<=12; j++)
            {
                random = rand()%5;
                colornumber[random]++;
                filledCircleRGBA(rend, x1, y, radius, RColor[random], GColor[random], BColor[random], 255);
                x1 += 2*radius;
            }
            y += 50;
        }

        if(i%2==0)
        {
            int x2 = 2*radius;
            for(int j=1; j<=11; j++)
            {
                random = rand()%5;
                colornumber[random]++;
                filledCircleRGBA(rend, x2, y, radius, RColor[random], GColor[random], BColor[random], 255);
                x2 += 2*radius;
            }
            y += 50;
        }
        

    }

    for(int i = 1; i <=30; i++) {
        int x = rand() % 5;
        while (colornumber[x] == 0) {
            x = rand() % 5;
        }
        filledCircleRGBA(rend, 300, 700, radius, RColor[x], GColor[x], BColor[x], 255);
        SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    }


    while(chance != 0){


        chance--;
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    //Until it gets a key pressed
    SDL_Event *e = new SDL_Event();
    while(e->type != SDL_KEYDOWN)
        SDL_PollEvent(e);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using a while loop in order to solve the problem, but I could not and the balls were coming down more than I wanted them and they also were in different colors from what I had first seen on my screen

Comment: For "gradually" set some delay between balls drawing. Or better, use a timer and clear the screen, then draw all balls in their proper positions.

Comment: You need to have a main loop, which must include the event loop `while (SDL_PollEvent(...)) {}`, updating ball positions and rendering. Enable vsync to prevent the main loop from running too fast. [Fix your timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) to make sure the ball speed is independent from FPS.